# Python import error: No module named toolkit.rd

Tags: python, importerror

I have installed a third party library according to its instruction using

```
python setup.py install
```

the library is now located in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

However when calling

```
from myLib.toolkit.rd import myFunction
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named toolkit.rd
```

The folder structure is `myLib->toolkit->rd.py`. myLib and toolkit folder contain an `__init__.py`. I also added the path to python path environment variable but that did not help either.

So I'm kind of lost why this isn't working?

EDIT:

```
from myLib.geometry import distance_to_point
```

where geometry.py contains function `distance_to_point` results in following error:

```
ImportError: No module named geometry
```

So something with this library is just wrong. I have a lot of other libs installed and they all work with no issue. Note that I did restart PC. Just to make sure...

Comment: Make sure you are not using `virtualenv` .

Comment: What does that mean? how do i do that? EDIT: OK, this is a package I have never heard of and I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `myLib/__init__.py` not empty with an `__all__` definition that not expose toolkit submodule.

Comment: while it is not empty, it does not contain an __all__definition.

Comment: Can you put the content?

Comment: it just defines 2 global variables containing stuff a non-expert in the specific field can make no sense of.